# Angular 4 html for loop displaying loosely typed object (string) normally but not when element is extracted directly?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 to develop an app which is mainly about displaying data from DB and CRUD.

Long story short I found that in Angular 4 the component html doesn't like displaying loosely typed object (leaving the space blank while displaying other things like normal with no warning or error given in console) even if it can be easily displayed in `console.log` output, as shown in a string.

So I made a function in the service file to cast the values into a set structure indicating they're strings.

So now something like this works:

HTML

```
...
<div>{{something.value}}</div>
...
```

Component.ts

```
...
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.pkey = params['pkey'];
    this.service.getSomethingById(this.pkey)
        .then(
        something => {
          this.something = this.service.convertToStructure(something);
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    });
}
...
```

Code of the function `convertToStructure(something)`

```
convertToStructure(someArr: myStructure): myStructure {
    let something: myStructure = new myStructure();
    something.value = someArr[0].value;
    return something;
}
```

But as I dig into other files for copy and paste and learn skills from what my partner worked (we're both new to Angular) I found that he did NOT cast the said values into a fixed structure.

He thought my problem on not being able to display the values (before I solved the problem) was because of me not realizing it was not a plain JSON object `{...}` but an array with a single element containing the object `[{...}]` .

He only solved half of my problem, cause adding `[0]` in html/component.ts was not able to make it work.

Component.ts when it did NOT work

```
...
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.pkey = params['pkey'];
    this.service.getSomethingById(this.pkey)
        .then(
        something => {
          console.log(something[0].value); //"the value"
          this.something = something[0]; //html can't find its value
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    });
}
...
```

HTML when it did NOT work

```
...
<div>{{something[0].value}}</div> <!--Gives error on the debug console saying can't find 'value' of undefined-->
...
```

And of course when I'm using the failed HTML I only used `this.something = something` instead of putting in the `[0]`, and vice versa.

So I looked into his code in some other page that display similar data, and I found that he used `*ngFor` in html to extract the data and what surprised me is that his html WORKED even if both of our original data from the promise is identical (using the same service to get the same object from sever).

Here's what he did in html:

```
...
<div *ngFor="let obj of objArr" ... >
  {{obj.value}}
</div>
...
```

His html worked.

I'm not sure what happened, both of us are using a raw response from the same service promise but using for loop in html makes it automatically treat the value as strings while me trying to simply inject the value fails even if `console.log` shows a double quoted string.

What's the difference between having the for loop and not having any for loop but injecting the variable into html directly?

Why didn't he have to tell Angular to use the set structure indicating the values are strings while me having to do all the trouble to let html knows it's but a string?

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is as you said that your JSON is not simple object , its JSON Array and to display data from JSON array you need loop. So, that is why your friends code worked and yours did not. And please also add JSON as well.

Comment: But I did try something like `objArr[0].value` in html or assigning `objArr[0]` to `obj` before using `{{obj.value}}` in html and both didn't work. If you mean putting array in html itself and put `[0]` won't work then what about the second method?

Comment: tell me what is the error on your console when you try above mentioned ways.